# Responsive images for > 1 aspect ratio images (taller than wider)

Tags: html, css, responsive

### Hi,

Like everyone know for have a fluid image (responsive) in css we need to use:

```css
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

This code work like a charm when we have a > 1 aspect ratio (wider that taller, like the 99% of the images).

---

Now, I have this markup:

```html
<div class="circle-bg">
 <img src="pathto/myimage.png" alt="" class="phones">
 </div>`
```

That look like this

[image: phone]

This image is inside a `div` that have a setted width and height, like so:

```css
.circle-bg {
height: 1000px;
width: 800px;
```

Now, in theory the image should fill the 100% width without overflow the container but in practice I must to set a width and height also for the image, like so:

```css
.phones {
width: 100px;
height: 500px;
```

Infact if I don't explicity the size it become:
[image]

As you can see, not very beautiful, and the css snippet for responsive image doesn't work.

### How can I fix that behavior?

**Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xuwcat4r/

Comment: Did you try object-fit: scale-down ?

Comment: Please, provide the HTML snippet.

Comment: have you tried setting the `img` tag to `display: block;` ?

Comment: Your desired result seems to be not very clear. Please update your question with the desired result and a [mcve] displaying your attempt and your actual result.

Comment: @ThanveerShah I 
I've already tried object-fit: scale-down

Comment: @sagar1025 
I've already tried also display block. None of them work for me

Comment: Provide the codepen for this . So we can play around to understand whats going on

Comment: Done, provided fiddle @ThanveerShah

Comment: If there isn't anything else to add in the issue for make it better and more clear, I suggest to someone to reopen the issue 

Answer (score 0):

Initially you need to `position : absolute` property to the `.phones` class to be able to move it as desired in the container.

In short your css should be

CSS

```
.circle-bg {
  width: 740px;
  height: 737px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Basic responsive, doesn't work */
img {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  position : absolute;

}

/* positionate images to the center */
.phones {
  position: absolute;
   left : 142px;
   top : 72px;

}
```

Above mentioned CSS works here as https://jsfiddle.net/xu3o9bvd/

Comment: Look that work very nice, but I Hope if there Is some solution a Little bit more modular.

Comment: Means what do you excatly want?And is my answer worth deleting?

Comment: Because, I have a lot of images like that (images that are taller than wider) and set for each image, a height and width can  become a little uncomfortable. Simply, I want to the images to fill the parent container, without overflowing